# Using a pointer to get multiple outputs of a function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, directx

I'm attempting to use pointers to get multiple outputs from a function. I pass in a pointer (pointed to NULL for init purposes), and the function fills out said pointer and returns its failed/success value.

Inside the function the pointer is getting passed into, everything is fine. It gets initialized. Once we step out, however, the old value is thrown away, and its somehow NULL again.

I have a feeling there's a correct number of asterisks and ampersands that I'm supposed to use here, but I'm not quite getting it.

Obligatory code:

```
ID3D11Buffer* Vout;
g_pDxManager->CreateVertexbuffer(&Vout, vertexes); //This isn't getting changed
```

Inside CreateVertexBuffer()

```
HRESULT DxManager::CreateVertexbuffer(ID3D11Buffer** out, Vertex3p vertexes [])
{
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = (sizeof (Vertex3p1c) * 3);
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData;
    initData.pSysMem = vertexes;
    initData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    initData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    HRESULT hr = m_pDxDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, (ID3D11Buffer**) &out);
    if (hr == S_OK) g_pLogger->log("DxManager::CreateVertexbuffer(): Successful.", 1, false, false);

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with casts: you can lie to compiler but he will revenge.

Comment: `(ID3D11Buffer**) &out` looks wrong. Why are you casting? Try passing `out` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HRESULT hr = m_pDxDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, (ID3D11Buffer**) &out);
```

The last parameter should just be `out`: no ampersand, and no cast.

i.e. The above line should be:

```
HRESULT hr = m_pDxDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, out);
```